# Getting the last id in telerik menu for mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

i'm using telerik controls for mvc in the menu component i'm facing a weird problem that it posts the last id in the collection such that if i have `moduleID`s =23 and 21 all i get at the server is 21 i have the following code

```
menu.Add()
      .Text(items.ModuleName)                   
      .Content(() =>
                {%>
                  <%Html.RenderAction("ContentDocument", new { id = items.ModuleID });%>
                    <%});
                }
```

it seems like the Action is called once the menu code is finished loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that the telerik menu requires a string i solved it by using `string.Format` like

```
.Content(string.Format("{0}", Html.Action("ContentDocument", new { id=items.ModuleID })));
```

hope it will help somebody else in future.